# Firebug and cURL

Tags: tls, firefox, curl

I have been using Firebug and cURL for quite a while.

Firebug is amazing to capture HTTPS POST request as opposed to a network analyser as it is aware of SSL/TLS negotiation. And cURL is amazing to resend that POST request after modifying parameters.

When I use firebug, I "Copy as cURL" a (HTTPS) POST request, and replay it from a Terminal.
[image]

However when I replay this in Terminal, the response that I can see is encrypted.
[image]

Questions:

- Can I decrypt that Terminal output ?
- Can I inject that cURL POST in
  the browser (firefox) to see the WebServer response decrypted ?

Thank you

Answer (score 15):

It's not encrypted, it's compressed. In your request, you send "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" so the server is compressing the response for optimization.

You need to remove the `-H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"` and you should see the normal response.

OR

You can install gunzip if not already installed and pipe your curl command as `curl [...] | gunzip -`.

Comment: To add a little extra context: cURL could not successfully complete the connection over HTTPS if it was not already natively handling the SSL/TLS encryption.  The fact that you're getting data at all means that the encryption has been successfully negotiated.  I don't, offhand, know if there's a way to have cURL natively handle the compression, I imagine so, but r00t's suggestion is sufficient and probably preferred.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to download a file to disk rather than piping it into Terminal, just add `-o filename.zip`
The -o flag says you're specifying a destination file name.

Comment: Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.